# EditorJS : Sanitze HTML in client the best way

Tags: strapi, editorjs

I'm using [editorJS with Strapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-react-editorjs) (back) and NextJS (front).

Acutally, I sanitize the data directly in the frontend with a custom parser.
It's working fine, but I've got an issue when I paste content from Word, it adds a span with some style tag.

This is the part when I transform the data from editorJS to a paragraph block

```
 paragraph: function (e) {
      return "<p>" + e.data.text + "</p>";
    },
//e.data.text = <span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial;>Example</span>
```

I want to get rid of all the style. What's the best method ?
Should I sanitize the HTML in the strapi or keep it like this in the front app ?

Comment: did you find solution or get resolved please help me